# что изучить из python для такой шкалы? Нужно написать прогу анализа для лаборат. показателей их 2000 и к каждой должна получатся такая шкала

Tags: python

изучала основы python
знаю, что нужно использовать условия (if, elif, else)
проблема именно в незнании визуализации как на картинке

[image]

Comment: начните с [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index)

Comment: потом pyqt5 (для визуала)